# Java Appium Automation Memory Testing

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

have a set of automation scripts that were written in Java TestNG with Appium running across iOS and Android devices. What I'd like to do is at certain intervals when performing certain actions, check the available memory of the device, or the memory that the application under test is using. The purpose of this would be to find memory leaks and/or other performance issues over a period of time.

I am aware of using the Instruments tool in OSX to track memory, but I'd like to do this checking programmatically such that it can be contained into our CI process and data can be collected over a period of time instead of manually.

Any tips/tricks on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I found this a great ideia!
Sadly, I don't know how to do this, but maybe, catching the memory of Instruments could be achieved easier than catching the memory used by your app, have you ever tried this?